# Removing products from your cart

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, delete

Currently the only way to remove a product on the cart page is if you enter 0 in the quantity field and click update shopping cart. Is there any settings I can enable or extension I can use to add a remove button on each line item?

I have found http://pradeepsanku.wordpress.com/tag/delete-product-from-cart-in-magento-programmatically/ which I could use to build my own extension but wanted to see what was available first before wasting my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default functionality of magento, more than likely it was removed from your custom theme. To add it back go to

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Add

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>
```

Also see [How to get url to remove product from cart in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138223/remove-item-from-cart-for-a-given-product-id).

Comment: Or it could also have been hidden via CSS.  You can check by going to the My Cart page and viewing the source then searching for 'btn-remove'.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has this functionality out of the box, you will probably find it has been removed from your particular theme template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In "**cart.phtml**" after

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
```

**Insert:**

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

**And insert button in form tag:**

```
<button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-update" id="empty_cart_button"><?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></button>
```